# Where can I get performance cost for each node in each mode for Blender?

Tags: materials, shaders, performance

I've thought it would be extremely helpful for the procedural materials optimization to know the exact performance cost of each node in the Shader Editor, if not in the absolute values than at least in the comparison to each other. For example as far as I know some math operations are cheaper than the others: adding/subtraction are cheaper than multiplication which is much cheaper than division, etc. Do you have any idea of how to get this information about Blender nodes or at least where to start a search or how to formulate a request?

**UPD.** Everything I found out so far is that Math node uses math.h standard C library for computations. I haven't found exact computation costs for its particular functions, but found this [wiki article about computational complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations), which seems like something that could be helpful... if I'd been familiar with calculus or whatever it is about.

Comment: Its possible to show execution times per node in a Geometry Nodes graph. But it doesn't seem like that's enable for the Shader editor. It might be possible to code and addon that would do this.

<<EDIT>> NVM, looking at the commit for the addition of the GN timings overlay, it's definitely not trivial to add.

Comment: Of course having a feature showing exact CPU/GPU/RAM usage and compilation/rendering time for each node right inside Blender would be just mind-blowing, but even if there were any info about actual algorithms used in each node it would help a lot. I'm sure everything can be found in the source code, but it is way too difficult for me to read it, even to find exact functions which determine nodes behavior.